# Storing a groupby group in a Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to join two datasets in Pandas. What I want to do is put the results of `df2.groupby('BuildingID')` into a new Series in `df1`. The reason being that the building ID is the level I'll be working with, while the ItemID is a collection of items within the building.

Example:

```
df1
BuildingID  Blah    ...
3   'a' ...
4   'b' ...
5   'c' ...
7   'd' ...

df2
ItemID  BuildingID  EnergyID    ...
7   3   2   ...
11  3   11  ...
12  3   12  ...
13  4   2   ...
14  5   12  ...
15  4   10  ...
16  7   2   ...
17  7   3   ...
```

So that I end up with the following:

```
df1
DataID  Blah    Grouped
3   'a' <groupby object>
4   'b' <groupby object>
5   'c' <groupby object>
7   'd' <groupby object>
```

So my questions are 1, how do I achieve this and 2, is it a good idea or is there a better way of representing this data - perhaps with suffixed headings for all the headings in each group?

Comment: You are using groupby without doing anything group specific. Why not just join df1 and df2 to create a df with a MultiIndex of 'BuildingID' and 'ItemID'? The groupby object also contains a all groups, you probably dont want to store it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend a bit on what you want to do next, but i would go for something like:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

indf1 = StringIO("""BuildingID  Blah
3   'a'
4   'b'
7   'c'
7   'd'
7   'x'""")    

indf2 = StringIO("""ItemID  BuildingID  EnergyID
7   3   2
11  3   11
12  3   12
13  4   2
14  5   12
17  4   10
17  7   2
17  7   3
17  7   4""")

df1 = pd.read_csv(indf1, delim_whitespace=True, index_col='BuildingID')
df2 = pd.read_csv(indf2, delim_whitespace=True, index_col='ItemID')

dfboth = df1.merge(df2, right_on='BuildingID', left_index=True, how='left')

dfboth.set_index('BuildingID', append=True, inplace=True)
dfboth.reorder_levels(['BuildingID', 'ItemID'])

                  Blah  EnergyID
BuildingID ItemID               
3          7       'a'         2
           11      'a'        11
           12      'a'        12
4          13      'b'         2
           17      'b'        10
7          17      'c'         2
           17      'c'         3
           17      'c'         4
           17      'd'         2
           17      'd'         3
           17      'd'         4
           17      'x'         2
           17      'x'         3
           17      'x'         4
```

Comment: That works fine with the simple data set here (and is essentially what I want to do) but when I try it on the full data set it tells me `Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` at the `merge` step.

Comment: I cant replicate that on v0.11, even with duplicate keys in both DataFrames. What version do you use? Update: I have edited my answer with some duplicate indexes which still work for me. Wether having a non-unique index is usefull remains to be seen of course.

Comment: I'm also on v0.11. I'm trying to cut down the real dataset now to see what's the simplest version that produces the error.